# Cannot connect to internet inside tensorflow docker image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am trying to learn how to run a python code using tensorflow inside docker images.

This is train.py which uses MNIST data.

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

This is my Dockerfile I use tensorflow GPU image and copy train.py in root directory.

Dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter

COPY train.py /root/train.py

CMD ["/usr/bin/bash"]
```

I built the image using :

```
docker build --tag tensorflow-image --network=host .
```

and ran the container using :

```
docker run -it tensorflow-image bash
```

When inside the container I try to run python3 train.py it doesn't download the MNIST data. I thought there is a problem with internet inside the container so I tried apt-get update. Turns out it cannot connect to internet. Is there any way to connect to internet inside the container?

EDIT :

```
root@9fcb3cea6deb:~# python3 train.py 
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz
```

It just shows this and doesn't download the dataset.

```
root@9fcb3cea6deb:~# apt-get update
Err:1 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease                                                                             
  Could not connect to developer.download.nvidia.com:443 (152.199.39.144), connection timed out
Err:2 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease                                                                 
  Unable to connect to developer.download.nvidia.com:https:
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                          
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                        
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                        
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                         
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/InRelease  Could not connect to developer.download.nvidia.com:443 (152.199.39.144), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/InRelease  Unable to connect to developer.download.nvidia.com:https:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

EDIT 2:

```
root@1edacaef7fcb:/tf# ping google.com
bash: ping: command not found

root@1edacaef7fcb:/tf# apt install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  net-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 194 kB of archives.
After this operation, 803 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 net-tools amd64 1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-tools/net-tools_1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

EDIT 3 : It started working when instead of :
docker run -it image bash

I used
docker run --network host -it image bash

Even though it started working I cannot understand the reason for it working now. Previously when I used run, I used without specifying the network bridge. Why all of a sudden do I need to specify it?

Comment: have you tried `ping google.com`
Can you add the screenshot for the above command too?

Comment: I have added the output.

Comment: Have you tried the answer in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1130898/no-internet-connection-inside-docker-containers

Comment: I have kubernetes too in my system and if I do this it might hamper my kubernetes installation. I have previously used internet inside docker images and it worked when I build it with --network=host tag.